# Does Log4j2.15.x/ greater versions require java/jdk8 + for compilation?

Tags: log4j2

In the document provided by Log4j2.x it clearly says that it requires jdk8+ but , my question here is ,doest it require jdk8 + on both runtime and compile time ?
Because am facing some issues when it is  compiled with jdk7.
However my runtime machines are running in jdk8.

Comment: Can you describe the issues?

Comment: The class files are not being compiled. And i could only empty folders after packaging.

Comment: Does Maven output any errors during compilation?

Comment: No errors during compilation and packaging. Where as if I compile it with jdk8+ , I can see the classes folder.But with jdk7 , am not able to see

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.